# Java - Mouse out of window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, mouselistener

How do I know if the mouse if out of the window I made and from which side it exited. I'm making a classic pong game and when I move my mouse out too fast, the 'thing' stays some pixels in. I'd like it to move to the edge of the window where it exited.

```
private class MouseMotion extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseMoved(e);
        int x = e.getX();
        p1.move(x);
    }
}
```

and the move function

```
public void move(int x) {
    if (x < 0  ) {
        this.x = 0;
    }else if(x+width > Main.screenSize.width - 1){
        this.x = Main.screenSize.width - width - 1;
    } else {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

I just need to know a way to know if the mouse is out of the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for [`MouseListener.mouseExited(MouseEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseExited%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look this:

```
Point mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

This tells you were the pointer is on the screen. No matter if your application has the focus or not. No matter if the pointer in on top of your window or not.

Comment: Then you are putting this code in a MouseListener.move() block, right? Put it somewhere else in your game loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseExited() and then get the coordinate from the event generated, using event.getPoint().

Comment: `MouseExited()`  There is no such method (given Java method names are case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this somewhere where it will get run and getting rid of the MouseMotion class. 'c' is the JComponent that p1 is getting drawn to, I don't know what you called that object in your code. 'running' is some boolean that is set to true. When this code is run, p1 will move according to the mouse until 'running' is set to false.

```
new Thread(()->{
    while(running) {
        p1.move(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX()-c.getLocationOnScreen());
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Isn't this a _little_ bit late?

Comment: @usama8800 Stack exchange isn't just so that people can get their own questions answered, it is made so other people with the same question can find a question that has been already answered, and only need to ask a question if nobody else has asked it before.  I posted an answer so that other people with similar problems can find the right answer here, because there were no good answers here already and I had to look on a different website to find the answer. I answered here so anyone else with this question can have the answer if they come here without having to wait for a response.